# How to stop auto reload of web page while using Live Share in VS Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, page-refresh, autoreload, live-share

Me and my colleague have an issue while using **Live Share** in **VS Code**. We are working on the same project shared via **Live Share**. So the problem is, whenever me or my colleague edits the code in VS Code, the **web page reloads every time**.

Is there a way to stop this behavior? or can you share any alternative methods?

Also, if possible please share any links or key words which might be helpful.

We have tried disabling auto-save of VS Code, but it didn't work.

Comment: When you say "edit", do you really mean "edit and save"? It only live reloads when I save.

Comment: I don't see any setting to disable live reloading. If you only make CSS changes, then by default, there shouldn't be any reloading, since the extension can inject CSS changes without reloading (see the `liveServer.settings.fullReload` setting). There's also the `liveServer.settings.wait`, which allows you to control delay in milliseconds before live reloading happens.

Comment: @user Sorry for the late response. 

The reload happens whenever we type on the keyboard. So on each keyboard button click, the local webpage reloads. Again, just for clarity, we are using Live Share Extension in VS Code to work on the same project in real time.

I will try the above suggested solution and get back to you soon.

Comment: Thank you @user. I delayed the reload of Live Server settings as per your suggestion. Now the annoying problem is gone.

Comment: ..... for what?